# Cloudera Sqoop Import SQL query trouble "where" clause

Tags: mysql, cloudera, sqoop

I have a db in cloudera. Using two of the tables, I am trying to find the `account` records that have only 1 device recorded in the `accountdevice` table. To do this, I have generated the following query:

```
[training@localhost ~]$ sqoop import -P \
> --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/loudacre \
> --username training \
> --target-dir /ZXS107020/loudacre/pset1 \
> --split-by accounts.acct_num \
> --query 'SELECT first_name, last_name, acct_num, city, state FROM accounts JOIN accountdevice ON (accounts.acct_num = accountdevice.account_id) WHERE $CONDITIONS AND count(accountdevice.account_id) = 1'
```

However, this doesnt work and produces the following message:

```
18/02/02 07:13:16 ERROR manager.SqlManager: Error executing statement: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid use of group function
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid use of group function
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:996)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3823)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2435)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2582)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2530)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1907)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2030)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:753)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:762)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnInfoForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:270)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypesForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:241)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypesForQuery(SqlManager.java:234)
    at org.apache.sqoop.manager.ConnManager.getColumnTypes(ConnManager.java:304)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.getColumnTypes(ClassWriter.java:1833)
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1645)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:96)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:478)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
18/02/02 07:13:16 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: No columns to generate for ClassWriter
    at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1651)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:96)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:478)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:605)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
```

The tables I am working with are structured as follows:

```
mysql> describe accountdevice;
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| account_id        | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| device_id         | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| activation_date   | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| account_device_id | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe accounts;
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| acct_num       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| acct_create_dt | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| acct_close_dt  | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| first_name     | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| last_name      | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| address        | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| city           | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| state          | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| zipcode        | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| phone_number   | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| created        | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| modified       | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

The query that I am trying to run is this: select the account information for clients that have exactly one device registered.

What am I doing wrong? I have tried using `'WHERE $CONDITIONS AND'` as well as using `"WHERE \$CONDITIONS"`

Comment: Did you try running the same query in the MySQL ?

Comment: @rob- no I havent, will try to do that now...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest running the query in MySQL first which will give you a validation that query is working fine. I think there is something wrong with the query.

The other problem you have to consider is The sqoop import `--query` option is intended to process a single statement and there are warnings about using complex queries.

From the sqoop Doc :

> The facility of using free-form query in the current version of Sqoop
>   is limited to simple queries where there are no ambiguous projections
>   and no OR conditions in the WHERE clause. Use of complex queries such
>   as queries that have sub-queries or joins leading to ambiguous
>   projections can lead to unexpected results.

**Suggestion 1 :** Run the query in mysql and push the data to a new table in mysql and import the records with sqoop from the new table.

**Suggestion 2 :** Create a stored procedure in mysql with the complex query you want to run and call it through the `--query` option in sqoop import. Something like below:

```
-- creating the stored procedure in my sql
mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE simpleprocforimport (OUT param1 INT)
    -> BEGIN
    ->   SELECT first_name, last_name, acct_num, city, state FROM accounts JOIN accountdevice ON (accounts.acct_num = accountdevice.account_id) AND count(accountdevice.account_id) = 1;
    -> END//

#From the sqoop import just call the procedure as below
sqoop import -P \
--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/loudacre \
--username training \
--target-dir /ZXS107020/loudacre/pset1 \
--split-by accounts.acct_num \
--query "CALL simpleprocforimport (@a);"
```

I'm not in mysql Env to test out, but let me know if you ran into any issues.

Comment: `mysql> "select first_name, last_name, acct_num, city, state from accounts join accountdevice on (accounts.acct_num = accountdevice.account_id) where count(accountdevice.account_id) = 1";
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"select first_name, last_name, acct_num, city, state from accounts join accountd' at line 1`

Comment: Am I running the query correctly through the command line interface though?

Comment: `ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function` - this confuses me because I havent use the group function in the query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164429/discussion-between-rob-and-zsad512).

Comment: Try this query : select first_name, last_name, acct_num, city, state from accounts, accountdevice where accounts.acct_num = accountdevice.account_id group by first_name, last_name, acct_num, city, state having count(*) = 1

Comment: please check the chat